# how to filter based by current year and lastyear?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table year with values like this ('2013','2014','2015','2016')

I want to filter values current year and last year
results of searching by current yea and last year like this ('2016','2015')
how to filter based by current year and lastyear?

Comment: Years are stored as comma separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `year()` function:

```
where col in (year(curdate()), year(curdate()) - 1)
```

However, if the column actually contains strings, then you should convert these to strings for performance reasons:

```
where col in (date_format(curdate(), '%Y'),
              date_format(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 year), '%Y')
             )
```